# How to disable default browser autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autocomplete, dom-events

How to disable default browser autocomplete when I use AutocompleteService for an input field
AutocompleteService - changes autocomplete="on"

Comment: What is AutocompleteService?

Comment: provide working code example, please...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what  AutocompleteService is but for most forms just set html input autocomplete flag to off.
Look at the example below.

```
<input type='text' autocomplete='off' >
```